# Файлы /var/log/lastlog и faillog давно не обновляются

Tags: ubuntu, авторизация, логирование

Я хочу выяснить, входил ли кто-то или пытался входить в мой аккаунт в мое отсутствие в Ubuntu 14.04.

В [документации](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles#Non-Human-Readable_Logs) сообщается о файлах `/var/log/lastlog` и `/var/log/faillog`, которые хранят эту информацию,
и предназначенны для чтения программами.
У меня эти файлы есть, но они давно не обновляются:

> /var/log$ ls -l faillog
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 32192 сент. 30  2015 faillog
>   /var/log$ ls -l lastlog
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 293752 февр. 18 15:33 lastlog

Естественно, команды

> $ lastlog -u user-name

и

> $ faillog -a

показывают устаревшую информацию.

Я бы хотела понять, **почему они не обновляются, и как это исправить.**

Интересующую меня информацию я нашла в файле `/var/log/auth.log`, но там не совсем понятно. Время от времени он перебирает всех пользователей, и про каждого пишет что-то вроде

> Jul 17 18:02:05 mymachine lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Jul 17 18:02:05 mymachine lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
>   Jul 17 18:02:05 mymachine lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "ХХХ"

Что бы это значило?

**Update:** По совету [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/22647/244413) попробовала заходить с консоли (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), с правильным паролем и с неправильным. Файл `/var/log/lastlog` обновился, так что с ним все в порядке. А `/var/log/faillog` не изменился:(.
Вышеупомянутый ответ предлагает проверять логины командой `ck-history --last`. (Для этой команды требуется установить пакет `consolekit`.) Результаты получаются какие-то странные:

> $ date
>   Пн. июля 18 17:29:21 IDT 2016
>   $ ck-history --last | grep Jul\ 18
>   lightdm   LoginWindow Session66  Seat1   tty7         :0                           Fri Jul 18 17:26 - 17:32  (00:06)
>   lightdm   LoginWindow Session65  Seat1   tty9         :2                           Fri Jul 18 16:54 - 16:55  (00:00)
>   ХХХ                  Session64  Seat1   ???                                       Fri Jul 18 16:54 - 16:54  (00:00)
>   ХХХ                  Session63  Seat1   ???                                       Fri Jul 18 16:54 - 16:54  (00:00)
>   ХХХ                  Session62  Seat1   ???                                       Fri Jul 18 16:54 - 16:54  (00:00)
>   ХХХ                  Session61  Seat1   ???                                       Fri Jul 18 16:54 - 16:54  (00:00)
>   ...

Обратите внимание на день недели.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/22528/416190