# Файл /var/log/faillog не используется, почему?

Tags: linux, debian, безопасность, авторизация

Частично данный вопрос без ответа поднимался [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545865). Суть в следующем.

Есть файл с неудачными попытками авторизации в систему faillog. Как можно увидеть по времени обновления, полтора года он никем не использовался.

```
/var/log$ ls -laht faillog 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24K May 11  2016 faillog
```

Отсюда вопросы:

1. Используется ли он в принципе?
2. Если да, то кем?
3. Как воспроизвести ситуацию, чтобы там появились новые данные?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял из исходников, при отсутствующем PAM этот файл используется программой `login` и его поведение управляется настройкой `FAILLOG_ENAB` в файле `/etc/login.defs`. Но так как PAM используется везде, правильность сего я на практике не проверял, но настройка похоже игнорируется.

При наличии PAM (а он чуть менее чем во всех современных линуксах) этот файл управляется модулем `pam_tally`, который нужно предварительно включить. Как это делать, пожалуй лучше поискать отдельно, но вот такая настройка, написанная первой строчкой в файле `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` (стырено из [enSO](https://askubuntu.com/a/108438)):

```
auth required pam_tally.so per_user magic_root onerr=fail
```

позволила получить какой-то вывод в команде `sudo faillog` после попытки залогиниться как root с неправильным паролем:

```
Login       Failures Maximum Latest                   On

root            0        0   01/10/18 17:56:37 +0300  127.0.0.
```

Почему файл раньше использовался, а потом вдруг перестал использоваться — не знаю, но по-моему вам должно быть виднее :) На моём дебиане 8 этого файла вообще не существовало, пока я `pam_tally` не включил.

Comment: А вообще лично я [тупо парсю /var/log/auth.log своим кривым кодом](https://github.com/andreymal/stuff/tree/master/authloghackers) :D

Comment: Не отслеживал этот файл ранее, не могу знать, когда он появился точно.